# RegEx match for string in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am looking for an easy way using regex to change the format of a string.
this is what I have

```
POL-CAD-OPT-1-15-31Oct14
INS-DOT-OPT-5-7-13Jun14
BOL-GUP-OPT-5-5-28Oct14
```

this is what it should be

```
POL-CAD-OPT-01-15-31Oct14
INS-DOT-OPT-05-07-13Jun14
BOL-GUP-OPT-05-05-28Oct14
```

right now I am using old split feature to construct the string using if length = 1 then add 0.

is there anything I can do with RegEx ?

Comment: You could probably use the replace functionality in RegEx...would have to search to show you as I haven't done it for ages.  +1 though for proper use of RegExes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit per comment below :
use this pattern
`-(\d)(?=-)` and replace with `-0$1`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/93)

```
-                        '-'
(                        group and capture to \1:
  \d                       digits (0-9)
)                        end of \1
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  -                        '-'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: that works but some string like this one, is having issue.. POL-CAD.OPT-4-6-29Sep14.IP